# Find missing value in an adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I am trying to find a missing event for the **Label ID**. Each **Label ID** has two different events associated with it. Those two events are *'Unload'* and *'Distributed'*. Some of the **Label IDs** have the *'Unload'* event, but are missing the *'Distributed'* event. I want to find the **Label IDs** that are missing *'Distributed'* event.

I don't know how to tackle this issue in Excel. I am attaching the snapshot of this spreadsheet but I have approximately 3000 rows of data. In the snapshot you would find other events but those can be ignored for the purpose of what I am trying to do.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

[image: Spreadsheet Snapshot]

Comment: @pnuts - I know how to use PivotTable but tbh I don't think PivotTable would solve my problem in this case. However if you know the way that this can be solved with PivotTable, I am open to suggestions!

Comment: I agree with @pnuts in that a PivotTable should work for your issue. Using that would allow you to pivot the data multiple ways to find what you want. However, can you show us what you have attempted that didn't work so that we can better assist you? Have you tried conditional formatting to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist not to use a PivotTable, you can stick this into another column and just filter by it:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,G:G,"DISTRIBUTED"), "Was distributed", "Was not distributed")
```